# Upload File with IFormFile .NET Core MVC is showing error of Required File

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, iformfile

After Selecting the file form Choos File, submitting the form showing error "The *formFile* field is required."

[image]

**Model** is here:
In **Debug** mode *formFile* value is set; it shows null;

```
    public class FileUploadTest
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile formFile { get; set; }
        public string fromFileUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

**View** is here:

```
@model UdyogWeb.Models.FileUploadTest

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="FileUploadTests" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"  ></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="formFile" class="control-label">Upload File</label>
                <input asp-for="formFile" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="formFile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
           @* <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="fromFileUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="fromFileUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="fromFileUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Controller** is here:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,fromFileUrl")] FileUploadTest fileUploadTest)
        {
            string folderurl = " ";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (fileUploadTest.formFile != null)
                {

                    folderurl = "casefile/brieforwrit/";
                    folderurl += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileUploadTest.formFile.FileName;
                    //fileUploadTest.fromFileUrl = folderurl;
                    string serverfolderurl = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folderurl);
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(serverfolderurl, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await fileUploadTest.formFile.CopyToAsync(fs);
                    }

                }
                fileUploadTest.fromFileUrl = folderurl;
                fileUploadTest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                _context.Add(fileUploadTest);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(fileUploadTest);
        }
```

In this project, I uploaded some files on the Identity Rejor page and it's working perfectly.

Please help to solve this error
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have tried once again on the same project on a different pc also *shows the same error *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Debug mode formFile value is set; it shows null;

You need to  bind your `formFile` too.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,fromFileUrl,formFile")] FileUploadTest fileUploadTest)
        {...}
```

result:

[image]